# OnDrawGizmos not drawing all Grid positions in generated Grid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, iequatable

I have a Grid I am generating to perform path finding. When storing all the walkable Nodes I perform a check if the `Obstacles` HashSet has an obstacle placed there. I am passing a `Node` to the `IsCellOccupied(Node node)` function but I think `.Contains` is failing to recognise the passed in Node.

Pastebin
[Grid.cs](https://pastebin.com/87rQH8Mc)

The Node class inherits `IEquatable` However using this and implemeneting `public bool Equals(Node other)` method produces an odd result of the Grid where many empty spots can be found. Only where the red obstacles are placed the area should be empty and not green.

[image]

Removing the `IEquatable` inheritance and it's method produces the full Grid. However, the whole Grid is now being generated even under the obstacles, where it should be empty

[image]

I can't seem to figure out where it's going wrong. I think it has to do with the `.Contains` check performed by the `IsCellOccupied` function but I am not sure what I am missing.

### Node

```
public class Node : IEquatable<Node>
{ 
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public Node parentNode {get; set;}

public Node(Vector3 position, CellType cellType, int cost)
{
    Position = position;
    CellType = cellType;
    Cost = cost;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Position.GetHashCode();
}

public bool Equals(Node other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return GetHashCode() == other.GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType()))
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        Node n = (Node)obj;
        return Position == n.Position;
    }
}
}
```

### IsCellOccupied Function

```
private bool IsCellOccupied(Node node)
{
    if (Obstacles.Contains(node))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

### Implementing suggested changes

Suggestion was to set the y as 0. This seems to still place a green node where an obstacle is.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return new Vector3(Position.x, 0, Position.y).GetHashCode();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be found in the PlaceObject function of Grid.cs

```
var cellPosition = new Node(new Vector3(positionX, 0, positionZ), CellType.Land, 1); 
...

var objectPosition = cellPosition; // <- objectPosition references the same object!

objectPosition.Position = new Vector3(
    objectPosition.Position.x, 
    ObstaclePrefab.transform.position.y, // <- you are altering the y component here
    objectPosition.Position.z
);
```

This does make sense, until you get to your `GetHashCode()` implementation.

```
return Position.GetHashCode();
```

The y component of your vector is not zero anymore, it is based on your obstacle.  So now if you try to compare a new node with y=0, there will be no match (unless obstacle y component is zero).

```
if (!IsCellOccupied(new Node(new Vector3(x, 0, z), CellType.Land, 1)))
```

We can test this in unity with a couple of Debugs.

```
var v1 = new Vector3(3, 0, 3);
var v2 = new Vector3(3, 1, 3);

Debug.Log($"V1) {v1.GetHashCode()}");
Debug.Log($"V2) {v2.GetHashCode()}");

// Outputs:
// V1) 1347420160
// V2) -1370488832
```

**The Solution**

Ignore the y component of `Position` in your `GetHashCode()` function.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return new Vector3(Position.x, 0, Position.y).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have implemented changes as you have suggested but it still does not seem to ignore where obstacles are placed and just adds a green node there anyways. I will update the post to show the output.

Comment: It looks like there is one other place where position is being directly compared, inside of the Equals function of Node.  `return Position == n.Position;`  try changing this to use GetHashCode() instead.

Answer (score 0):

try instantiating the obstacles in your grid way and the object that will be instantiated is modified as an obstacle  instead of making the whole thing through scripts